# How do i set up asp.net web forms app to send smtp email on windows 7 so i can test?

Tags: asp.net, smtp, system.net.mail

I am trying to test send email thru smtp in asp.net web forms app on windows 7. I get timeout. I am using my fastmail account to test with. I am pretty confused at this point as i am not sure if i also need to set up smtp email thru my iis console manager. Here is the settings i have in my console manager first. I am confused to how this process works. Does asp.net app first send to smtp email then send it to fastmail smtp?

smtp email page

```
     e-mail address: "is set to my fastmail address"
     deliver email to smtp server is checked.
     smtp server: mail.messagingengine.com   
     use localhost is unchecked
     port: 25   fastmail port is 465 but was told to set this to 25 
     authentication settings: i have this set to my email address and password
```

here is the session state page

```
    session state mode settings: in process
    cookie settings
    mode: use cookies
   name: asp.net_sessionid
   use hosting identity for impoersonation is checked
```

next here is my web.config file in the asp.net app

```
    <system.net>
      <mailsettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from"roger &lt;myname@fastmail.us&gt;">
          <network host="mail.messagingengine.com" userName="myname@fastmail.us" password="myemailpassword" port="465" enableSsl="true"  />
      </smtp>
     </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
```

next here is my c# behind code

```
        protected void btn_send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try { 
    string sendername = txtbx_name.Text.ToString();
    MailMessage mymessage = new MailMessage();
    mymessage.Subject = txtbx_subject.Text.ToString();
    mymessage.Body = txtbx_message.Text.ToString();
    mymessage.From = new MailAddress("george@georgebush.me", sendername);
    mymessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail address", "Roger"));        

    SmtpClient mysmtpclient = new SmtpClient();
    mysmtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    mysmtpclient.DeliveryMethod   = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        mysmtpclient.Send(mymessage);            
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string message = ex.ToString();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);

    }
}
```

am assuming the html and css isnt needed here. Any help is appreciated. I cant even get an error to catch in try catch statement. I am pretty lost at this point as i am new to asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your code is correct, you must add address for:

```
 mymessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("myemail address", "Roger"));
```

Instead of "mymail address" just put an email address

Did you check your setting file, you forgot an equal mark after from as below:

```
<smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from"roger &lt;myname@fastmail.us&gt;">
```

Comment: that is my email address there("myemail address")

Comment: i ended up using smtp4dev software. works great for testing. I still have a couple questions about win 7 and smtp. Is smtp e-mail a smtp server. It is confusing. I also wanted to know how do i unblock a ip address in windows 7 to use smtp e-mail. Am guessing after some research that is my issue. Anyways sorry for wasting anyones time who looked at this. I am new to asp.net.